# Conditionally change the image source based on its id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

How can I set or change the image using JavaScript or jQuery? The `src` attribute of `img` tags with `id` less than or equal to 3 (that is, `img` with `id` as 1, 2, 3) should be changed to (or set to) flower image, then that of `img` tags with `id` as 4, 5, 6 be animal image and that of `img` with id more than 6 (that is, 7, 8) be the default image.

I want to do this using the lesser than and greater than operators (< and >) but I don't want to use a button. I want it to happen automatically when I update the image. Is that possible?

I tried to do this but it is not working.

```
<div id="image"> 
<img id="img-1" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-2" src="..... "/>
<img id="img-3" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-4" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-5" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-6" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-7" src="..... "/> 
<img id="img-8" src="..... "/> 
</div>
```

Please answer with the full code using the image that make me understand.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid html. Please provide us with the real code.

Comment: what do mean by less then 3 and post the code, what you tried so far(Javascript / jquery).

Comment: Not entirely sure what is being asked please be more clear what you want the javascript to do. What I can make out of this, it looks to be some sort of carousel. If so just use owl carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're looking for. Consider adding some details in your question. BUT: I made an example of how you at least can change the src or an image.

The easiest way (not the BEST, or most intelligent way) is to change the `src` attribute on your images. I made a fiddle to show what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/nbhey2nz/ In short: When you click on the first button, it changes the src on images 1-3. When you click on the second button, it changes the src on images 4-6.

HTML:

```
<div id="image">
 <img id="img-1" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-2" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-3" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-4" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-5" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-6" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-7" src="..... " />
 <img id="img-8" src="..... " />
 </div>

 <div>
   <button id="oneToThree">
     Change 1-3
   </button>
   <button id="fourToSix">
     Change 4-6
   </button>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#oneToThree").click(function(){
    $("#img-1").attr("src", "http://www.small-hydro.com/images/home_btn_small.jpg");
    $("#img-2").attr("src", "http://www.small-hydro.com/images/home_btn_small.jpg");
    $("#img-3").attr("src", "http://www.small-hydro.com/images/home_btn_small.jpg");
  });

  $("#fourToSix").click(function(){
    $("#img-4").attr("src","https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus-Over.gif");
    $("#img-5").attr("src", "https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus-Over.gif");
    $("#img-6").attr("src", "https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus-Over.gif");

  });
})
```

---

UPDATE!
If I understand your updated question correctly, you want to do this with an operator `<` and `>` right?

Well, I updated my fiddle to suit your update: https://jsfiddle.net/nbhey2nz/2/ This time doing it in a JavaScript way, so you get both versions. Notice I changed the image ID to only the integer, not the `img-1` way. You could do it this way too, but then you would have to trim the text, and that's kind of not what you were asking about! ;)

HTML:

```
<div id="image">
 <img id="1" src="..... " />
 <img id="2" src="..... " />
 <img id="3" src="..... " />
 <img id="4" src="..... " />
 <img id="5" src="..... " />
 <img id="6" src="..... " />

 </div>
 <div>
   <button id="oneToThree">
     Change images
   </button>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#oneToThree").click(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++){
      if(document.images.item(i).id <= 3){
        document.images.item(i).src = "http://www.small-hydro.com/images/home_btn_small.jpg";
      } else if(document.images.item(i).id > 3 && document.images.item(i).id < 6){
        document.images.item(i).src = "https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus-Over.gif";
      } else {
        document.images.item(i).src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png";
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: yah i want to use < and > but i dont use a button. i want it automatically when i update the image. is that can?

Comment: Sure you can! Just use the timing event in JavaScript. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Just copy and paste this..., Not sure how data is comming. if it is comming through ajax then you need to use setinterval.
Might be it will work, if not please let me know (amitq7000@gmail.com)** 


    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Image change by areraj</title>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

      <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#image img#img-1").attr("src","http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2-small-flowers.jpg");
        $("#image img#img-2").attr("src","http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-small-flowers.jpg");
        $("#image img#img-3").attr("src","http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
        $("#image img#img-4").attr("src","http://cochraneanimalclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/smallAnimal.jpg");
        $("#image img#img-5").attr("src","http://cochraneanimalclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/smallAnimal.jpg");
        $("#image img#img-6").attr("src","http://cochraneanimalclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/smallAnimal.jpg");
       });
      </script>
      <style>
      img{width:50px; height:50px; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="image"> 
        <img id="img-1" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-2" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/>
        <img id="img-3" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-4" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-5" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-6" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-7" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
        <img id="img-8" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```